# read parameter from current url in angular js and jsp

Tags: angularjs, url, parameters

> Hi friends, I want to read parameter from current URL of the page in
>   `angularJS`. My page URL is
>   'http://localhost:9999/ADMIN_APP_0.1/Security_Question.jsp?user_id=1'.I
>   want to read this user_id in Security_Question.jsp
>   I googled and I got something Route in angular but my code style and its style is quite different.And I don't know about route.
>   Forgot password is jsp page which is calling security question page

```
 Forgot_Password.jsp

var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);
app.controller('forgotController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.listOfSecurityQues=[];

    $scope.getAvailableUser = function() {
    var loginId= {
                "user_login" :$scope.loginid
        };
        window.alert(" login ::::"+loginId);

            var response = $http.post('loginController/loginidAvailable', loginId);
            response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            window.location="./SecurityQuestion.jsp?user_id="+data; 

            });
            response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert( "Exception details: " +data+"  "+status);
            });

            //Empty list data after process
            $scope.list = [];

        }; // end of getAvailableUser


        Security_Question .jsp

    var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);
   app.controller('forgotController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,
    $http) {
            $scope.listOfUserSecurityQues = [];

            $scope.getUserQuestions = function() 
            {
               //here i want that URL user_id
               var response = $http({method : 'GET',
               url : "loginController/getUserQuestions"+user_id
                });

               response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                        $scope.listOfUserSecurityQues.push(value);
                    })
                })
                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                })
            };//end of getQuestions()


        } ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

by using $location we can read parameter of url.

```
    app.controller('Controller', ['$scope','$http','$location',
        function($scope, $http,$location)
        {
          $scope.Id=0;

          $scope.getUserQuestions=function(){

                    var url = $location.search();

                        angular.forEach(url,function(value,key){
                            $scope.Id=parseInt(value);
                            window.alert($scope.Id);
                        })  }
```